# How to integrate IBM worklight with react-native app?

Tags: react-native, ibm-mobilefirst

Our team was using `Ionic/Cordova` with `IBM worklight(7.0)`. Recently we got an opportunity to try out **react-native** and we need the `worklight` integrated with the application.

How do we integrate `IBM worklight` with react-native application?

Answer (score 0):

In general you need you to create a React Native project like any other, and add to it the MobileFirst Native iOS SDK as you also would add it to any other native iOS project (by following these instructions: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-with-the-mfp-sdk/)

You can find detailed instrustions and a video in the following blog post: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/06/03/react-native/

The blog post does mention an important aspect of the integration to take note of:

> Below I think one of the more important chunks of code to integrate React Native for iOS with the MobileFirst Platform Foundation. The code chunk is the MobileFirst Platform Foundation Adapter invocation call from the file ResourceRequest.m being exported into the React Native javascript code. In this section of code there are two important React Native methods. One being RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(); which will allow you to export a native class into the React Native javascript. The other is RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(...) this class explicitly tells React to expose this class's method for use in the React Native javascript. Exporting the particular method below is going to pass in a path named "path" and also a callback named "results." The adapter call is getting a list of movies stored as JSON data to a particular path (this path ended up not being needed). Then that data is passed as the callback into the React Native code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WLResourceRequest.h"
#import "ResourceRequest.h"
@implementation ResourceRequest
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getJavaAdapter:(NSString *)path results:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSLog(@"Invoking GET Procedure...");
  NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:10080/HelloMobileFirst/adapters/MoviesAdapter/getStories"];
  WLResourceRequest* resourceRequest = [WLResourceRequest requestWithURL:url method:WLHttpMethodGet];
  [resourceRequest sendWithCompletionHandler:^(WLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString* resultText;
    if(error != nil){
      resultText = @"Invocation failure.";
      resultText = [resultText stringByAppendingString: error.description];
    }
    else{
      resultText = response.responseText;
      callback(@[[NSNull null], resultText]);
    }
  }];
}
@end
```